# How to listen Entity Extension written event?

Tags: shopware6

Currently, I can see the entity extension data in request body but it is not included in product written event payload.

[image: request body]

[image: dump data in subscriber]

Is it possible to listen entity extension written event?

Comment: There are database events for all entities, e.g. `product.written`. More info here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/using-database-events#event-overview

Comment: thank @jim but it does not help

Answer (score 0):

Every entity in shopware should dispatch a written event when it's saved.
So like `product.written` when a product is saved, there should also be a similar event when your entity is written. It should be triggered automatically, and it's `your_entity_name.written`.